# NavigationManager.NavigateTo not navigating

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have an issue that the NavigationManager.NavigateTo is not navigating in a certain case.

To reproduce this issue you can create a new Blazor Web App and add a new page:

```
@page "/test"

@attribute [StreamRendering]

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h3>Component</h3>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Test();
    }

    private async Task Test()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

In this case the NavigateTo works.
But when I change `OnInitializedAsync` to this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var task = Test();
    await Task.WhenAny(task);
}
```

Then it does not work. Does someone know and can explain why this is the case?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tested it with .NET 8 RC2.

Comment: Please state in the text which pre-release version you tested this with. rc2 came out yesterday.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, still works in my test. (no [StreamRendering])

Comment: Thanks @HH for the hint. Yes, I already used .NET 8 RC2. Haven't considered that it could have something to do with that version.

Comment: I opened an issue for that: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51288

Comment: I've just done some testing and agree.  If you change it to `Task.WhenAll()` then it works.  `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` raises the `NavigationManager.LocationChanged` event.  The  `Router` has registered for this event and changes the loaded page component.   With `WhenAny` the event is not being raised.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no actual solution, but a workaround due to how Task.WhenAny works and Microsoft won't fix or change this anytime soon.

So the current workaround is to either **not use `Task.WhenAny` inside OnInitializedAsync** or to **await it twice:**

```cs
await await Task.WhenAny(task);
```

> That is, Task.WhenAny returns a Task. Hence, the double await is expected.
>
> ~ quoted from the linked issue

*A solution was provided inside the github issue Tobias has linked inside his comment above. I just wanted to provide an answer here so people don't have to search for the commented link and scroll through conversation.*